# How would you convert a UTC date to an epoch in DB2?

Tags: db2

I can do this to get UTC

```
select CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE AS utc 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

one would imagine something like

```
select GetEpoch(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE) AS utc
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

what would be the logic for GetEpoch?

Answer (score 1):

If your Db2-database lives either on Linux/Unix/Windows or i-series and is currently supported by IBM, then you can use the EXTRACT function which accepts an EPOCH parameter (among other things).

For EPOCH, Extract Returns The number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.00 for the supplied date/timestamp expression.

Example `values extract(epoch from current timestamp)` or `select extract(epoch from current timestamp) from sysibm.sysdummy1`

Db2-LUW documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053629.html).

Db2-for-i documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaextract.htm).

Although the EXTRACT function is available on Db2-for-Z/OS, it does not appear to accept the EPOCH parameter, unless undocumented, documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_extract.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the same result in both rows:

```
VALUES 
  extract(epoch from current timestamp)
, (days(current timestamp) - days(timestamp('1970-01-01'))) * 86400  + midnight_seconds(current timestamp)
```